# On the commutation of two self-adjoint operators

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

It's well known that two self-adjoint commuting operators have a common set of eigenvectors (see, for example, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264704/simultaneous-diagonalization-of-self-adjoint-operators-on-hilbert-space)). But... isn't it *always* the case?

Isn't the composition of two self-adjoint operators self-adjoint?
If so, then they should always commute, for $AB=(AB)^*=B^*A^*=BA$.

Comment: No the composition of two self-adjoints is not self-adjoint $(AB)^* = B^* A^* = BA$ so all you have to do is find self-adjoint elements that do not commute, which always exists in a non-abelian C*-algebra.

Comment: Following your "if so", it appears that the composition of two self-adjoint ops is self-adjoint if and only if they commute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The composition of two self-adjoint operators might not be self-adjoint. For instance, over $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual inner product, consider $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which satisfy
$$ AB=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, $$
which is not self-adjoint.

Comment: Is there a "Big List of 2x2 Counterexamples in Operator Theory"? :>)

Comment: @KeithMcClary It is surprising how many times people don't even bother to check things for $2\times 2$-matrices.